# How to use postman to test the call of my api

Tags: json, api, vue.js, web-frontend

i am currently building an frontend app to display a generated qr code from an api. I started to implement the code but got a problem with the parsing of the response

here is the frontend code with the call

```
<template>
  <div>
   <p>test</p>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

// Configuration
let myConfiguration  = { 
    "Account" : "CH4431999123000889012",
    "CreditorName" : "Muster AG",
    "CreditorAddress1" : "Hauptstrasse 1",
    "CreditorAddress2" : "8000 Zürich",
    "CreditorCountryCode" : "CH",
    "DebtorName" : "LivingTech GmbH",
    "DebtorAddress1" : "Dörflistrasse 10",
    "DebtorAddress2" : "8057 Zürich",
    "DebtorCountryCode" : "CH",
    "Amount" : "1.50",
    "ReferenceNr" : "21000000000313947143000901",
    "UnstructuredMessage" : "Mitteilung zur Rechnung",
    "Currency" : "CHF",
    "QrOnly" : "false",
    "Format" : "PDF",
    "Language" : "DE"
}

// Call function to create invoice
let myFile = generateQrInvoice(myConfiguration);

// Work with binary data
if(myFile != null) {
    // ...
}

function generateQrInvoice(myRequestConfiguration) {
    // Main configuration
    let myEndpointUrl = "http://qrbillservice.livingtech.ch";
    let myEndpointPath = "/api/qrinvoice/create/";
    let myApiKey = "(falseApiKey)";

    // GET parameters
    let myGetParams = new URLSearchParams(myRequestConfiguration);

    // Perform request
    fetch(myEndpointUrl + myEndpointPath + "?" + myGetParams, {
        method: "GET", 
        mode: "cors", 
        cache: "no-cache", 
        headers: {
            "APIKEY": myApiKey, 
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(function (myResponse) {
        try {
            // Check status
            if(myResponse.status == 200) {
                // Read and parse JSON
                let myJsonObject  = JSON.parse(myResponse);

                // Check if error
                if(myJsonObject["isSuccessed"] == "true") {
                    if("base64Content" in myJsonObject && myJsonObject["base64Content"].trim() != "") {
                        // E.g. send file to client
                        let myBlob = new Blob(atob(myJsonObject["base64Content"]), {type: "application/pdf"});
                        let myBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
                        window.open(myBlobUrl);

                        // Return data
                        return atob(myJsonObject["base64Content"]);
                    } else {
                        throw "no data provided";
                    }
                } else {
                    throw myJsonObject["message"];
                }
            } else {
                throw "status code " . myResponse.status;
            }
        }
        catch(e) {
            // Handle exception
            console.warn("Error: " + e.message, e);
            return null;
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        // Handle exception
        console.warn("Error: " + err.message, err);
        return null;
    });
}
</script>
```

and here is the response i get when i inspect on the browser :

```
Error: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Response]" is not valid JSON SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Response]" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at app.vue:61:42
```

I  didn't write the apikey here but it is written on my code.

As it has been a long time since i didn't code like this, i don't really see yet how to tackle the problem. I tried to test with postman but it appears my request is not good yet.

If someone has an idea, i would be very happy to learn.

Thank you very much in advance,

Eugene

Comment: could you please console.log **myJsonObject** ?

Comment: I just tried now and he desn't let me. The error message in vue is : 
Error: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Response]" is not valid JSON SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Response]" is not valid JSON  13:54:02
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/eugenecarmona/Documents/qrbill/app.vue:55:42
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: What is the data inside `myResponse`? If `myResponse` is already a JSON then you don't need to parse it again. You can verify that first.

Comment: So i just console log the response, especially the heard list: 
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(6) {
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'server' => [Object],
      'x-powered-by' => [Object],
      'x-powered-by-plesk' => [Object],
      'date' => [Object],
      'content-length' => [Object]
    },